# C# Linq kvp.Any() in where clause

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

In C# Linq, I'm trying to construct a database query with a where clause like:

```
WHERE (Column1 = 1 and Column2 = 2) or (Column1 = 3 and Column2 = 4) or .....
```

I have a `List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>` as the data I want to pass into the `Where` clause. I have to use a KVP instead of a Dictionary because the keys are not always unique. Here is my Linq query:

```
var result = context.Table
    .Where(a => kvp.Any(k => a.Column1 == k.Value && a.Column2 == k.Key))
    .Select(a => a.Id).ToList()
```

However, this throws the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException : The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Table>
    .Where(a => __kvp_0
        .Any(k => a.Column1 == k.Value && a.Column2 == k.Key))' could not be translated.
```

I'm using EntityFrameworkCore version 3.1.5.

Any thoughts on what might be causing this exception? Is there a better way to resolve this?

Thanks!

Comment: EF Core 3.x changed the translation process to ensure more consistent performance - unlike 2.x, it does not automatically switch to client processing. You can switch manually (e.g. `AsEnumerable`) but then you take responsibility for pulling entire tables to your client. EF 3.x can't translate many local collection queries like collection`.Any` to SQL, but you can build your own extension to translate using [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit).

Comment: You would have to build up the expression that represents that predicate. LINQKit can help with that but is not a necessity.